# Determinant of Jacobian of matrix multiplication

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, determinant, jacobian

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$. We consider the map
$$f_A : \mathbb R^{n \times n} \to \mathbb R^{n \times n} ,\quad X \mapsto AX.$$
By considering easy examples of $A$ one comes up quite fast with the conjecture
$\det(D f_A) = \det(A)^n$. Here $D f_A$ is the Jacobian matrix of $f_A$.

Is there an elegant proof which does not result in a long confusing computation?

**Idea (edit):** I just came up with an idea. Obviously, the statement has only to be proven for non-singular $A$. They are generated by elementary matrices. So it suffices to consider them since we have $f_A \circ f_B = f_{AB}$.

Comment: What does the Jacobian matrix have to do with anything?  Since $f_A$ is linear, wouldn't its Jacobian just be itself?

Comment: But to represent $A$ as a matrix in the usual way you have to do the trick that Thomas Peru has suggested in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $X$ to be $n$ separate column vectors and then stack them on top of each other to form one large column vector $x=(x_{1,1},x_{2,1},\ldots,x_{n,1},x_{1,2},\ldots)^\top$. The map $f_A$ can thus be represented by a block diagonal matrix $B$ of $n$ blocks, each block being $A$. The linear map $f_A$ can be viewed as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n^2},x\mapsto Bx$. The derivative of this linear map is just $B$. Its determinant is (block diagonal matrix!):
$$
\det(B)=\det(A)^n.
$$

Comment: Instead of $n$ separate column vectors you mean one large column vector.

Comment: Well view them as seperate column vectors and then stack them on top of each other to form one large column vector - it has both aspects.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ acts on each column of $X$. $Df_A$ gives the best linear approximation of $f_A$ at each point. But $A$ is linear and acts on each $n$-dimensional column vector. So $det(Df_A)$ is the volume of the unit parallelepiped after applying the best linear approximation of $f_A$ to each of its vectors, giving us that $det(Df_A)=det(A)^n$ since we are scaling each column vector by a factor of $det(A)$. Completely unrigorous of course, but that is my way of thinking about it conceptually.